# AWS Data Zone - Subscribe to data in a project in another domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-mesh, aws-datazone

**Context:**

I have three accounts:

- Account A: Central Governance Account, Data Zone in use to manage the Data Mesh with its domains
- Account B: separate account for the producer-aligned domain "SalesData", associated
- Account C: separate account for the consumer-aligned domain "SalesAnalytics", associated

I am able to successfully set up the two domains and publish and query the data assets in "SalesData" from Account A, Data Zone Data Portal.

**Problem:**

Now I want to subscribe to data assets in "SalesData" from "SalesAnalytics". It seems only possible for projects in the same domain to subscribe (see e.g. https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/datazone/create-subscription-request.html).

Is there a way for a project in domain "SalesAnalytics" to subscribe to data assets in domain "SalesData"?